# Улучшает ли auto increment primary key работу MySQL с таблицами?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Здравствуйте. Недавно узнал от одного человека, что использование auto increment primary key улучшает работу MySQL с таблицами, это так? Или правильным вариантом будет использовать только в тех случаях, где он нужен?

В каких случаях используют auto increment primary key?

Comment: Что значит "улучшает работу с таблицами" ?

Comment: @lDrakonl обработка запросов происходит быстрее

Comment: Обработка выборки по известному значению ключа разумеется проходит быстрее, если по этому полю есть первичный ключ (или любой другой индекс). А автоинкремент он или нет значения не имеет

Comment: кроме того есть куча случаев, когда в таблице первичным ключом _должен_ быть набор из нескольких полей (например таблицы для обеспечения связи многие ко многим). В этом случае вообще отсутствуют колонки которым бы стоило быть автоинкрементными

Comment: @Mike большое спасибо

Comment: @Mike по поводу "А автоинкремент он или нет значения не имеет" не уверен. В InnoDB при автоинкременте лок при вставке используется, к примеру. Если ключ будет UUID, а не автоинкрементый int, то такого не будет.

Comment: @Suvitruf Жесть то какая. Хотя судя по доке поведение можно настраивать и тогда может даже получится без дополнительных тормозов обойтись ...